# How can I properly read/write a users cart items document in firebase firestore on iOS?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
class CartViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var cartItems = [Cart]()
@Published var errorMessage = ""

private var db = Firestore.firestore()


func fetchData() {
    
    db.collection("customers").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).collection("cart").addSnapshotListener{(querySnapshot, error) in
        
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("no documents")
            return
        }
        self.cartItems = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Cart? in
            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Cart.self)
            
        }
        if let error = error {
            self.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
            return
        }
        
    }
    
}}

struct Cart: Identifiable, Codable {
let db = Firestore.firestore()

@DocumentID var id: String?

var name: String
 var details: String
 var image: String
var price: Float
var quantity: Int

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "id"
    case name = "name"
    case details = "details"
    case image = "image"
    case price = "price"
    case quantity = "quantity"
}}
```

This is the code for the struct and viewmodel. I tried following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-yQeAf3bLE and replacing the Book with Cart. I am getting the following error in my CartViewModel "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". The editor highlights the = in the self.cartItems = documents.compactMap

Comment: Try simplifying the closure’s signature by removing the return type: `compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in`. See https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide for more details.

Comment: Side note: you don’t need to use the `CodingKeys`, since all your attributes match the document field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CartViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var products: [Product] = []
@Published var error = ""

var db = Firestore.firestore()
   func fetchData(){
    
    db.collection("customers").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).collection("cart").getDocuments { (snap, err) in
        
        guard let productData = snap?.documents else{return}
        
        self.products = productData.compactMap{ queryDocumentSnapshot -> Product? in
            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Product.self)
        }
        
    
    }
}
}

struct Product: Codable, Identifiable {
@DocumentID var id: String?
var product_name: String
var product_details: String
var product_image: String
var product_ratings: String
var product_size: String
var product_quantity: Int
var product_price: Int
}
```

This seems to be working correctly. Conforming to Codable. I don't know why but appending the items to a cartitem struct was not syncing with the database.

Comment: Could you please describe what exactly is going wrong and put all the code inside the code block

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).  While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are.  Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.